# Looking for a particular Common Lisp implementation

Tags: open-source, implementation, common-lisp

I'm looking for a Common Lisp implementation I ran across once, sometime in the past year or two.  I only remember a few things, and I don't know how to search for it based on these facts, so maybe somebody here can help.

- it was open-source, but wasn't one of the big ones (SBCL, CMUCL, MCL, etc.)
- it was likely incomplete; it looked almost more like an exercise in writing the simplest possible self-hosted Common Lisp
- the main webpage was plain black-on-white, and had 2 columns, where the left column was a link to the source file for a particular area of functionality (loop, format, clos, etc.), and the right column was a link to the tests for that functionality
- the source files themselves were pretty-printed for the web, with syntax highlighting that looked kind of like an old Redhat Emacs default config: slate-gray background, etc.

Where can I find this Lisp implementation?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to mention, what you were actually looking for: Sacla, a partial implementation of Common Lisp in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which one you are referring too, but you can find a list of Common Lisp Implementations [here](http://www.cliki.net/Common%20Lisp%20implementation).

Is there any particular reason why this Lisp is grabbing your attention now?

Comment: Found it on this list: http://homepage1.nifty.com/bmonkey/lisp/sacla/index-en.html

Comment: I'm looking because I want to read and possibly port parts of Common Lisp to another environment, and I want the simplest one I can find -- have you tried reading SBCL?  It's stuffed full of weird magic to make things go fast, but it's not exactly simple.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to pin down, but open-source + minimalistic + incomplete sounds vaugely similar to Paul Graham's [Arc programming language](http://arclanguage.org/).

Comment: No, it was definitely Common Lisp.